# How to work on MVC in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error Argument `'MyController' is not a function, got undefined` when I am trying to run code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>Hello world from Prateek</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.company}}</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function MyController($scope) {
      $scope.author = {
        'name': 'J Doe',
        'title': 'Designer',
        'company': 'ABC XYZ'
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to get the name, title and company to be displayed, instead I am getting output as below

`{{author.name}}
{{author.title + ', ' + author.company}}`

Comment: The global function controller syntax isn't available in newer versions of Angular (1.3+).

Comment: Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: You don't need a workaround. Just use Angular the proper way. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined any angular application in your javascript. You can define your controller using created module. Then you can access your controller from your views.
Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app ="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>Hello world from Prateek</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.company}}</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []); // definition of a module, you use myApp in ng-app directive in the html part so that angularJS initialize itself.
    myApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
      $scope.author = {
        'name': 'J Doe',
        'title': 'Designer',
        'company': 'ABC XYZ'
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That works great, but if I put the javascript into separate `controllers.js`, I am not able to see the output once again.

Comment: Did you include your new javascript in your html using `<script>` tag

Comment: Nopes, no tags. It looks like this could be a positioning problem, where to put the script tag when using `controllers.js`

Comment: You can put it at the end of `<body>` tag. If your controllers.js is at the same level with your index.html following will work <script src="controllers.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

you should create module first then create controller like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.author = {
        'name': 'J Doe',
        'title': 'Designer',
        'company': 'ABC XYZ'
      }
});
```

and in your html you should use `ng-app="module-name"` like:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```